azure devops yaml expression string to version
I want to check if a string is a version in an azure devops expression. Mainly for setting a version number. Here is my expression
- ${{ if tryparse(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], True) }}:
  - name: myBuildNumber
    value: $[Build.SourceBranchName]
  
- ${{ else }}:
  - name: myBuildNumber
    value: $[format('0:yyyy\.MM\.dd', pipeline.startTime)]

azure devops expression docs state that I use C#'s version try parse, but no real description on how to use this in a yaml expression. I know the C# docs call for an out parameter but I'm not sure how to call or use the function in this context.

There is no TryParse function in Azure DevOps.

The 'Version.TryParse' is not a user available function in Azure Pipelines. It a backend function for pipeline to parse the provided string to be a version number.
To check whether a string is a version number, you can try to use the if statement with the regular expression in the script.
See below example as reference.

The if statement "if('$(Build.SourceBranchName)' -match '^\d+(\.\d+){1,3}$')" can check whether the value of "Build.SourceBranchName" variable is a version number format string that contains a minimum of 2 segments and a maximum of 4 segments.

The logging command "SetVariable" is used to update the value of the "myBuildNumber" variable.


variables:
- name: myBuildNumber
  value: $[ format('{0:yyyy\.MM\.dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Show myBuildNumber before update'
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      Write-Host "Build.SourceBranchName = $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      Write-Host "myBuildNumber = $(myBuildNumber)"
    
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Update myBuildNumber'
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      if('$(Build.SourceBranchName)' -match '^\d+(\.\d+){1,3}$') {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myBuildNumber;]$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      }

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Show myBuildNumber after update'
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      Write-Host "Build.SourceBranchName = $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      Write-Host "myBuildNumber = $(myBuildNumber)"


I see what you're doing here. What i was trying to do is have my version number be pulled from the branch name, and if it isn't a valid version number, use the date as the version number. I was having difficulty with getting the build number to be sequential using a single counter. I changed to using multiple counters (one for the branch name and one for the pipeline date). i then do a similar regex check in a powershell script, updating the version number of the pipeline run.
